# Excel : Need to delete about 1 million blank rows

Tags: c#, excel, filtering, delete-row, vba

I have an excel file from one of our customers and the file has close to 1 million blank rows.

I did try filtering it on column C (called Items) where it is blank and then chose all rows and tried deleting. It almost froze for nearly couple of hours but at the end I had kill excel process.

I also tried below VBA script but the actual line where it says "r.rows(i).Delete" just freezes. This is for the 1st delete instance itself.

I have the excel file set to Manual for formula calculation also.

I don't mind the entire job taking few hours. I can leave it overnight and check in the morning.

If there is anything with VB.NET or C# that's also fine.

**Update  1:**  I can't do bulk delete as between 1 to 1048576 rows, I need to delete those rows where column C is blank (which means the row is blank).

**Update 2:** I marked the below deletion as the answer but I eventually ended up resolving the issue by copying the GOOD rows to another worksheet.

Please suggest the best options to handle this scenario.

VBA source

```
Sub BlankRowDelete()

Dim r As Range, rows As Long, i As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.EnableEvents = False
ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False
ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False

Set r = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A1048576")
rows = r.rows.Count
For i = rows To 1 Step (-1)
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(r.rows(i)) = 0 Then
        r.rows(i).Delete
        RowDeleted = RowDeleted + 1
    Else
        NotDeleted = NotDeleted + 1
    End If
    totalcnt = totalcnt + 1
    If RowDeleted = 100 Then
       TotalDeleted = TotalDeleted + RowDeleted
       RowDeleted = 0
       Debug.Print "count now is " + totalcnt
    End If
    Application.StatusBar = "Row count is " + totalcnt
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.EnableEvents = True
ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = True
ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = True
```

End Sub

Comment: How about deleting them in a block together, e.g. `Rows(“[1:1048576]”).EntireRow.Delete`?

Comment: First of all, insert a `DoEvents` above the `Next`.

Comment: @RickTeachey : I can't do bulk delete as between 1 to 1048576 rows, I need to delete those rows where column C is blank. Upon debug I find that when I step through the .delete command, it just freezes (forever). I kept if for like 45 mins and when I checked later, it was still frozen.

Comment: @KekuSemau : I have tried that. The issue is it not even coming out of the very 1st "delete" command.

Comment: What is the purpose of deleting row by row? Updating the staus bar is a waste of time - especially with having `Application.ScreenUpdating` set to `False`. Would it be okay to just delete the whole range in one hit?

Comment: `r.rows(i).Delete` looks odd, this will not delete the entire row, but only one cell and left shift the row. Do you need that? Anyway, can you not just sort by Column A, mark blanks and delete those entire rows manually?

Comment: @KekuSemau: r.rows(i).Delete -> I thought it deletes the row. I am not sure if it deletes cell by cell in each row?

Comment: No, `r` is only Column A, you could use `r.rows(i).EntireRow.Delete`. Again, if C is your key column, sort by C, mark empty rows manually downwards in one step and delete...?

Comment: How about just writing out all the rows you want to keep to a new file/spreadsheet instead?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen : I would like to try this approach as deletion is going to take more than 2 days. I guess I will have to loop through and create new worksheet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a few updates to your code such as the doevents, turning on  the status bar, since oyu are writing to it, and updating the screen when needed and adding cstr() when you write out an numeric value.  I ran this with no problem. as noted in the comments, this only deletes cell A not the entire row

```
Sub BlankRowDelete()
On Error GoTo myError
Dim r As Range, rows As Long, i As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.EnableEvents = False
ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False
ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False

Set r = ActiveSheet.Range("C1:C1048576") 
rows = r.rows.Count
For i = rows To 1 Step (-1)
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(r.rows(i)) = 0 Then
        r.rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
        RowDeleted = RowDeleted + 1
    Else
        NotDeleted = NotDeleted + 1
    End If
    totalcnt = totalcnt + 1
    If RowDeleted = 100 Then

       Application.ScreenUpdating = True
       TotalDeleted = TotalDeleted + RowDeleted
       RowDeleted = 0
                   'you can uncomment this but since this is a dup since writting to statusbar (imo)
      'Debug.Print "count now is " + CStr(totalcnt)

       Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    End If
    Application.StatusBar = "Row count is " + CStr(totalcnt)
    DoEvents
Next
myError:
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
MsgBox CStr(i) & ": " & Err.Description
End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.EnableEvents = True
ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = True
ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = True
End Sub
```

Comment: :I thought it would delete the entire row at one shot. What I am doing is stepping all the rows from bottom. and if the row is blank, then I am issuing delete command. As said in OP, it freezes here. You mentioned it deletes Cell A. so what's the command to delete entire row?

Comment: jsut need to tell it the entire row.  I updated the above code with; r.rows(i).EntireRow.Delete.  I also updated it to check column C

Comment: I am going to try it now.

Comment: Is there anything I need to do in above code for auto-save? or do I need to run any command for 'save'?

Comment: at the end jsut add ActiveWorkbook.Save

Comment: Process is still running but it shows count..Looks like it is doing 12,000 rows per hour (approx) and may take another 24 hours or so. If I hit ESC key multiple times, will it abort? and if it aborts it doesn't roll back deleted records? please suggest

Comment: hitting esc key stops the macro and does not roll back but you hard coded the range so it will start over and look at the entire range again.

Answer (score 0):

Sort the document in ascending order by the C column. Blank lines will go to the end, so it should be easy to delete them.

Comment: :That's what I have done but manual deletion just freezes for hours. So I am going the VBA route but with issues so far.

Comment: @pnuts : I tried that first time. It just froze. Now it makes sense to me because VBA script has deleted only 130000 rows in the last 14 hours.

Comment: @pnuts: The file seems fine to me but it takes to apply any formula to the column also. I am going to try the approach of creating new worksheet for GOOD rows.

Comment: @pnuts:I guess the new VBA script to copy GOOD rows to new worksheet should work even when they newer versions. Correct?